# Angular Interceptor: Http request is not being called

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, interceptor

I'm trying to get RefreshToken before each request and if it has expired I need to refresh it. The interceptor calls the service's function but I never get the API call. Please help

my interceptor code

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.authService.isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      return next.handle(this.addCookiesToRequest(request));
    }
    if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(result => result !== null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(() => next.handle(this.addCookiesToRequest(request)))
      );
    } else {
      this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
      return this.authService.refreshExpiredToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);
          return next.handle(this.addCookiesToRequest(request));
        }),
        catchError((error: any) => {
          this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
          return Observable.throw(error);
        })
      );
    }
  }
}

  public addCookiesToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }
```

authService refreshToken code

```
refreshExpiredToken() {
    return this.http.get(`${api_url}/token/refresh`, {
      withCredentials: true,
      observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        if (res.status >= 300 && res.status < 400) {
          window.location.href = res.url;
        }
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return of(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

I even tried to add somewhere .subscribe(), but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I didn't exclude the refreshToken URL from interceptor, that is why it was intercepting itself in an infinite loop, that is why it was never actually called.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the underlying problem is that you want to handle the referesh token state clent-side.

Aside from that, in your code your second if statement relies on the else statement: when *refreshTokenInProgress* is true the interceptor returns *refreshTokenSubject*, which will emit some value **only** in the else statement. In this way

```
 switchMap(() => next.handle(this.addCookiesToRequest(request)))
```

will never be triggered.

Comment: the problem is not with that line. I get to the ```return this.authService.refreshExpiredToken().pipe(``` line and then nothing happens, neither switchMap, nor catchError, because the http request for refreshToken never fires. But th service's function is being called and debugger goes into it.

Comment: And what do you mean by handling in client-side? I'm making a request to server to get new token

Comment: If I understood your code correctly, you return an observable that never emits values, that's why the return statement works  but you don't get any value. The lines you should check are `this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);` and   `this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);`.

Comment: this is not the case. Also that line that you write about is for other requests if they fired while the first one didn't fire yet because it is waiting for the refteshToken. And when refreshToken is refreshed - all the other requests will fire too